# What will be the lifetime of temporary instance?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {

    }
    A(A &copy)
    {

    }
};
void foo(A a)
{

}
int main()
{
    foo(A());
}
```

Will the temporary instance generated by calling `A()` be deleted after the copy constructor has ended or after the function foo has ended?

Comment: why dont you add a destructor, some `cout`s and see?

Comment: As it stands, the code will not compile - the signature of the copy constructor needs to be `A(const A &copy)`.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: You're correct although some compilers allow it as an extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The temporary is destroyed at the end of the *full-expression*. That means after `foo` has returned.

> A full-expression is an expression that is not a subexpression of another expression.